# How to Cluster switch over in Apache Pulsar with out duplicate data

Tags: java, spring-boot, sockets, apache-kafka, apache-pulsar

I have an use-case in Apache Pulsar consumer.There is a Producer which is producing messages to different two clusters (Cluster A & Cluster B) and to respective topics with same data at a time as a message(JSON is the produced message).

Here A is Primary cluster and B is like Secondary cluster.

**What I am trying**

I am trying to consuming the data and then processing it to CSV file and then to table on daily basis.It should be done based on cluster availability.

**Problem:**

When Cluster Primary is not available and/or not polling message to Primary(A) , then I need to switch over to Secondary(B).But If I consuming from Secondary then I will get the data from start because there is no acknowledgement is shared between the clusters.Because of this we will get  data redundancy problem.

For suppose if I started both at same time and storing only primary data and secondary only be consider on primary's fail over by waiting certain interval of time. In this case may have data loss possibility because I am waiting for certain interval time.

Is their any suggestions or ideas to over come my problem like switching on fail-over and storing to CVS's and to table with out data dependency and data loss.

I developed two consumer codes to consume the data One for A and other for B.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at Apache Pulsar geo-replication with replicated subscriptions:

https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/administration-geo/#replicated-subscriptions

This feature keeps the subscriptions between two clusters in sync. When messages are acknowledged on Cluster A that acknowledgment is updated on Cluster B. There is a small lag, so it is possible to get duplicate messages, but it avoids the problem of having to start reading from the beginning of the topic.

Comment: is this works with two different service urls and with different topics?

Comment: Yes, two different service URLs, one for each cluster. There is a topic on each, but they are essentially mirror images of each other.